# Where did the term "soccer" originate?

Tags: football, history

It seems that currently America is one of the only countries that uses the term "soccer" to refer to what the rest of the world calls "football".

What caused the Americans to start using this term instead of "football"?

Comment: Pretty thoroughly covered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_association_football, I think.

Comment: @Good timing, I heard the explanation just the other day.

Comment: At best this is a question for EL&U

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [Wikia entry](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_is_Football_called_%27soccer%27_in_the_US):

> Soccer became a shortened reference to the word as**SOC**iation football.

Comment: For a more in depth answer http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/06/the-origin-of-the-word-soccer/