# Why is Cricket called Cricket?

Tags: cricket, terminology

My daughter and I were playing softball and on the next field were a bunch of guys playing cricket.  She asked me Why is Cricket called Cricket?  I had no idea and figured this was a good place to find out.

Comment: Not sure if this is on-topic here, cf. http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28/where-did-the-term-soccer-originate (maybe EL&U would be a better fit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cricket#Etymology_2) and [BBC News](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/7919429.stm), the game and the word might originally be from Belgium (and “There is no way to relate the term to any existing English word”):

> Perhaps from a Flemish dialect of Dutch met 'with' de 'the' krik ketsen 'to ricochet', i.e. "to chase a ball with a crook".

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cricket) explains it this way:

> 1590s, apparently from O.Fr. criquet "goal post, stick," perhaps from M.Du./M.Flem. cricke "stick, staff," perhaps from the same root as crutch.